# How can I install cron on MSYS2?

Tags: msys2

How can I install cron (vixie-cron) on MSYS2 x64. I've searched and searched again but to no avail. 
I've tried pacman -S cron and pacman -S vixie-cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSYS2 don't have any cron package.